# NaN whilst calculating total values mapping over an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate a value every time I map over an array but I am getting (5)NaN back. If I hard code a single value in I get the correct value I am looking for. Looks like the problem is something to do with mapping over the values. If I console.log each value I get the correct numbers.

```
   console.log(calculateTotalReviews(16, 40)); returns: (5)40
   console.log(review.valueCount); returns: 16, 8, 6, 13,
   console.log(review.starRating); returns: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

```
        {customerReviews.map(review => (
            <CustomerRatingBar review={review} />
        ))}
```

```js
const customerTotalReviewsData = {
  totalNoOfReviews: 50,
  averageRating: 4.8,
};

const customerReviews = [{
    starRating: 5,
    valueCount: 16,
  },
  {
    starRating: 4,
    valueCount: 8,
  },
  {
    starRating: 3,
    valueCount: 6,
  },
  {
    starRating: 2,
    valueCount: 13,
  },
  {
    starRating: 1,
    valueCount: 7,
  },
];


const calculateTotalReviews = (amountOfCustomers, totalReviews) =>
  (amountOfCustomers / totalReviews) * 100;
  
console.log(calculateTotalReviews(review.valueCount, review.totalNoOfReviews)) // Returning (5)NaN
```

Comment: what is this return type: ```(5)40``` and ```5(NaN)```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it to show a [mcve]

Comment: You for example need `customerTotalReviewsData.totalNoOfReviews` instead of `review.totalNoOfReviews`

Comment: Its mapping over the data review is for each value, sorry I've added the map to make that clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only assume, that one of the values `review.valueCount` or `review.totalNoOfReviews` is `undefined`, which would make the calculation return `NaN`.

Looking at your variables, can it be that you want to use `review.valueCount` and `customerTotalReviewsData.totalNoOfReviews` (instead of `review.totalNoOfReviews`)?

```js
calculateTotalReviews(review.valueCount, customerTotalReviewsData.totalNoOfReviews)
```

Comment: Thankyou, the second value should be customerTotalReviewsData.totalNoOfReviews which is giving undefined

Answer (score 1):

review.totalNoOfReviews is `undefined`. Calculations done to it will result in `NaN`.

You might want to change your code to:

```
{customerReviews.map(review => (
            <CustomerRatingBar review={review} totalNo={customerTotalReviewsData.totalNoOfReviews}/>
        ))}
```

```
console.log(calculateTotalReviews(review.valueCount, totalNo))
```